# Count letter in a word from scanner, java

Tags: java, count, letter

My code is looking like this right now, it's counting the letters in the word but I would like my code to count every letter in the word so if I write `banana` or `nine`, the code will ask which letter to count, and if I choose "N", it will print 2 "N". Please help me out.

```
    System.out.println("Ange ordet du vill leta i: ");
    String str1 = sc.nextLine();

    System.out.println("Ange bokstaven du vill leta efter: ");
    String str2 = sc.nextLine();

    int count = 0;

    for(int i = 0; i < str2.length(); i++) {
        if(str2.charAt(i) != ' ')
            count++;
    }

    System.out.println("Antal bokstäver i ditt ord: " + count);
```

Comment: what exactly is your question?

Comment: You just need to alter the `if` to conditionally only be true if the character is the character you should count.

Comment: Also java is not javascript.  They are not related in any way.

Comment: You're really close. First, `str1` is the string you want to look through, so you'll need to modify the for loop to iterate through `str1` instead of `str2`. Then your if statement should be `if(str1.charAt(i) == str2.charAt(0)`. If you do this, you'll visit every character in `str1` and compare it to the first letter of `str2`, which should only contain one letter anyways. Optionally, you can add some input validation, so if the user puts more than one letter into `str2` or nothing at all, you can re-ask for input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to count every letter at first. You should count after getting the letter to count. But depending on the scenario. I assume that you need to get the count of the letter in a particular string.

You can wrap counting logic inside a while() to do this over and over again.

```java
import java.util.Scanner;

public class MyClass {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
    
      Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        
      System.out.println("enter word");    
      String s = scanner.next();
      
      System.out.println("enter letter");
          
      char a = scanner.next().charAt(0);
      
      int count = 0;
      
      for(int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++){
          if(s.charAt(i) == a){
              count++;
          }
      }
      
      System.out.println(count);
      
    }
}
```